# Another usage of @ operator in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I just found out something like this which works in C# code.

```
foreach (var item in list)
{
   Console.WriteLine(@item);
}
```

Can anyone explain how is this possible - I have not found any documentation in ECMA for this.

Comment: Maybe it was asp razor generated cshtml file ?

Comment: Is list a list of strings? I'm pretty sure it behaves like the normal @ before string literals.

Comment: It's so you can use keywords as variable names. Like `@this` won't function as a keyword.

Comment: I guess compiler is taking Console.WriteLine(@item) as a => Console.WriteLine(@""+item); Both the codes posses same result. This code works same for both line of codes.  -------   var list=new List<string>();
        list.Add("1");
        list.Add("2");
        list.Add("3");
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(@""+item);
            Console.WriteLine(@item);
        }

Comment: `@identifier` is mentioned in ECMA 334 - **9.4.2 Identifiers**

Comment: But this is not "int @class;" this is before some existing variable name so this is not what you refer to Richard, IMO